# PHP query audio files from mySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, audio

I have audio files uploaded to my PHP website. I have a mySQL database connected to the website with a table as shown in the screenshot in the following link:
[mySQL Table Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/enq2P.jpg)

Right now, when you enter a search on the website, it returns the corresponding yupikWord, englishWord, and audio entry from the table in the database. The audio entry is the name of the audio file located on the web server.

I need help: how do I make it so it returns the audio recording if it knows the name of the audio file located on the web server?

Here is my PHP code for the mySQL query:

```
<?php
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set('display_errors',1);

    include_once('db.php'); //Connect to database
    if(isset($_POST['q'])){
        $q = $_POST['q'];

    //get required columns
    $query = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM `words` WHERE `englishWord` LIKE '%$q%' OR `yupikWord` LIKE '%$q%'") or die(mysqli_error($conn)); //check for query error
        $count = mysqli_num_rows($query);
if($count == 0){
  $output = '<h2>No result found</h2>';
}else{
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){
    $output .= '<h2>'.$row['yupikWord'].'</h2><br>';
    $output .= '<h2>'.$row['englishWord'].'</h2><br>';
    $output .= '<h2>'.$row['audio'].'</h2><br>';
  }
}
echo $output;
}else{
"Please add search parameter";
}
mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

Here is HTML code for the search bar on my website:

```
<head>
<title>Search</title>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"/>
 </head>
 <body>
<form method="POST" action="search.php">
  <input type="text" name="q" placeholder="Enter query"/>
  <input type="submit" name="search" value="Search" />
</form>
</body>
```

Comment: Are you asking how to return a file, given you have the file's name? Would it be enough to output a link (an `<a href="">` tag) to the file, so that when a user clicks the link the browser downloads the file?

Answer (score 0):

If you put your audio in , the result will be text, not audio. So you need to put your audio link in  tag like this

```
<audio controls>
  <source src="/link/to/mp3/<?php echo $row['audio'] ?>" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>`
```

Hope this help.